# Handling Unhandled event loop exception in Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

We are developing a product based on eclipse (it's a eclipse plugin and we have around 60+ plugin projects), I am using log4j as my logging framework and using it to log errors on business logic side. But I am not finding a way to handle UI errors which Eclipse throws in case if there is any bugs in UI, example:

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed
```

I am talking about these type of errors. So how do I handle this exception so that I can log in our log files, so that bugs can be identified.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796560/centralized-exception-handling-for-eclipse-plug-in) stackoverflow question, basically it says override `public void eventLoopException(Throwable exception)` from `WorkbenchAdvisor` class.

I tried like this, in one of our UI plugin project like this:

```
public class CustomWorkbenchAdvisor extends WorkbenchAdvisor {
     @Override
    public void eventLoopException(Throwable exception) {
        System.out.println("Error occured");
        super.eventLoopException(exception);
    }
}
```

And I delbrately created UI error, but when I see my console, I don't see "Error occured" displayed instead it displays:

```
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
```

With stacktrace. Can anyone guide me how can I handle these type of errors?

Comment: How are you telling Eclipse to use your CustomWorkbenchAdvisor?

Comment: @greg-449, Yes that's where I have doubt. Should I configure it somewhere? I don't know.

Comment: You have to specify it in the PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench call which creates the application. This call is in the main application class specified in the <run> entry for the <application> extension point in the application plugin.xml.

Comment: @greg-449, can you post it as answer, so that I can check and accept it? :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify you customized `WorkbenchAdvisor` in the `PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench` call which creates the application. This call is in the main application class specified in the `<run>` entry for the `<application>` extension point in the application plugin.xml.

Comment: Hi, It works if I make it as a RCP application, but it doesn't work for plugins :(

Comment: For a non-RCP plug-in you could see if you can use the org.eclipse.ui.statusHandlers extension point to define a status handler.